# Excel VBA Copy and paste to different workbook at end of existing data

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am trying to combine data from several workbooks into one master workbook
I have 3 workbooks that all have a tab named company and I want all the data they contain to be pasted to a new workbook on the same tab.

I then want to be able to repeat this for 13 other tabs that do not have the same number of columns so I need it to find the last row and column rather than specifying the range

I have cobbled together the following code from a couple of sites but cannot get it to work. 
I keep getting error 1004 on the copy and paste part
Any advice would be appreciated. 
Thank you in advance

```
Sub Copy_Paste_Below_Last_Cell()

Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim lCopyLastRow As Long
Dim lastCol As Long
Dim lDestLastRow As Long
Dim lastRow As Long

  Set wsCopy = Workbooks("Source.xlsm").Worksheets("Company")
  Set wsDest = Workbooks("Target.xlsx").Worksheets("Company")

  '1. Find last used row in the copy range based on data in column A

      lCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    ' Get the last cell with data in row 1
    lastCol = wsCopy.Cells(1, wsCopy.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

  '2. Find first blank row in the destination range based on data in column A

  lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

  '3. Copy & Paste Data

    wsCopy.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lCopyLastRow, lastCol)).Copy
    wsDest.Paste Destination:=("A" & lDestLastRow)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the worksheet to `Cells()`, even if it's within `wsCopy.Range()`

```
wsCopy.Range(wsCopy.Cells(1,1), wsCopy.Cells(lCopyLastRow, lastCol)).Copy
```

You could do this in one line (I'll use `With` to make it a little easier to read:

```
With wsCopy
    .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lCopyLastRow, lastCol)).Copy wsDest.Range("A" & lDestLastRow)
End With
```

Comment: Thanks @BruceWayne exactly what I needed!

Comment: @Gac_100 - Yay! If this solved it for you, you can mark it as The Answer by ticking the check mark left of the post (below the up/down arrows).